# android - <activity-alias> manifest tag

Tags: android, android-activity

In Android, what is the purpose of < activity-alias > ? From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html), it seems that it is just another name for an existing < activity > with intent filters that override the target activity's filter (my understanding so far).

What is its practical use ?

Can a caller send an intent both to the target and the alias ?

Comment: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/01/16/preserve-your-launchers-use-activity-alias/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it seems that it is just another name for an existing < activity > with intent filters that override the target activity's filter (my understanding so far).

I'd define it as "providing additional filters", more so than overriding.

> What is its practical use ?

You can disable components, like `<activity-alias>`. You cannot disable `<intent-filter>` elements (though that'd be seriously handy).

Hence, if you have an activity that you want to be available all the time, yet only *some* of the time offer up a specific filter (or filters), `<activity-alias>` is for you.

A modern example of this comes courtesy of the new Storage Access Framework. It used to be that to make documents available to third-party apps, you would implement an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity, with an `<intent-filter>` advertising relevant MIME types (and, possibly, `ContentProvider` paths for a provider of yours). However, if you are adopting the Storage Access Framework on Android 4.4+, you don't want to *also* have the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity available -- the net effect is that everything of yours will show up twice. So, on Android 4.4+ devices, you need to either disable the whole activity (if you do not need it for anything else), or move the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `<intent-filter>` to an `<activity-alias>`, so you can disable it separately. This is covered in greater detail in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#custom).

TL;DR: I doubt that many developers use `<activity-alias>`, though it has its use cases (e.g., the launcher one cited in a comment on your question).

> Can a caller send an intent both to the target and the alias ?

Um, if by that, you mean "can I use `startActivity()` to start either the activity or the alias?", then, yes.